Datatable.Net rowgrouping include row columns in header
I have used the below javascript to convert my table as a datatable:
var table = $('#test').DataTable({
    pageLength: 60,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    bDestroy: true,
    //fixedHeader: true,
    //responsive: true,
    orderFixed: [[0, 'desc']],
    order: [[0, "desc"]],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            target: 0,
            visible: false
        }
    ],
    rowGroup: {
        dataSrc: 0
    }
});

This creates the header as such: 
The grouping is fine at dataSrc 0 which is correct, but I want to use the entire row 0 as the dataSrc and not just the first <td> and greyed out -- Is there anyway I can use the entire row as the group heading?
Or rather than grouping by the first column, can i group by every row with a class? the way my data is structured it includes Totals, which i would want included inside of the header
Have tried using the above code
